# How to update an existing Net core 5 App on IIS server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-10

I Have Net 5 asp.net core app hosted on server, with a lots of sub projects. In Asp.Net MVC 5 i was able to update these projects just by simply overwriting the dlls on host server. but it seems in net core this functionality is not working.

does net core not support this feature? this is a very big project and i cant always publish & upload whole projects whenever their is a small change in a single module.
i am using inprocess hosting, if that helps. i tried using app_offline to take application offline and then putting just the dlls but unfortunately it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's called publish. Right click on the project, click on publish and link it with your ISS server.

*Edit

My bad didn't read full question...

Comment: i know what publish means, i am  doing this from last 10+ years, read the question again

Comment: My bad, sorry. I've never tried to directly replace the DLLs, but just tried to do it on Azure Web Apps and it actually worked. Maybe is something about your ISS server configuration? Can you share the config?

Comment: its the default config for aspnet core, server is fresh installed with no quirky extensions

Comment: Maybe if you enable (if possible) server side error pages you'll get any feedback of what's going wrong with the server. That could get you some trace about the  possible errors.